# App Develompment with Minimum salesforce edition

Tags: appexchange, professional-edition, enterprise, editions, group-edition

I have to give suggestions to my clients about the Minimum Salesforce Edition require to build an app for AppExchange. I had gone through all the editions and had a detailed overview of all of them. I am now stuck between professional and Enterprise edition. I want to know any major kind of differences between them. 
And Also I want to know about the future of Group edition or any possibility to develop app on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edition they choose does not matter for purposes of development; your application will be created in a Developer Edition org, which is like an Enterprise Edition org but with limited storage space. They should choose whichever edition suits their business practices. For differences, see the [marketing material](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/). Enterprise has a lot to do with automation, such as workflow rules, API access, etc.

If they just need to get started, Professional Edition should be sufficient for their purposes. They can always choose to upgrade later. Group Edition has been replaced with Essentials Edition. It is typically not suited for anything more than the smallest of businesses. Again, this has nothing to do with development, so they should make their purchase decision based on their business needs.

Comment: If you look in the screenshot, it is saying that lightning platform is not included. I didn't understand this point.
https://pasteboard.co/I0a4V14.png

Comment: @Soul_In_Code That's not relevant to if they can do development, though, as the package will be in a Developer Edition org. It has to do with being able to use App Builder, apparently, but that only applies to the ISV's org, not to what they can create.

Comment: let say I am developing an App from the Developer Edition and having some functionalities which are using some automation features of the lightning platform. So what will happen if I will install the app into professional? (As it is metioned that Lightning Platform customize and Automate process are not available)

Comment: @Soul_In_Code that's a completely different issue, and one I'm not actually sure about. I suggest asking a new question to address that specifically. Again, their choice of which edition is used to run their ISV business is completely unrelated to the capabilities of the application being developed.